# Gitlab Runners when Gitlab server is down

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a question regarding Gitlab runners here. I've looked and searched quite much but haven't found any relevant information yet.
I'm going to update the Gitlab server for the company I work for, and we have many Gitlab runners.
There will be a down time for the Gitlab server update and I was wondering what will happen to the active Gitlab runners during this downtime?
Will the Gitlab runners function as normal after the update or will I need to register all runners again?

Anyone familiar with this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should work again as normal, but it depends how exactly the runners are set up. Where are the runners deployed?

E.g. for local development purposes i have deployed some runners locally via docker and mix their usage with the shared "company" runners.

Comment: Im relative new to Gitlab CI/CD but we run our runners on separate servers from the server where Gitlab is installed, and we also deploy our runners through docker.

Comment: To my knowledge you should be fine.

Comment: Please make sure you have a backup and keep to the docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/ .

Happy upgrading!